# Issue with displaying SQL result in DataGridView

Tags: .net, sql, database, vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to show the results of a SQL query within a data grid view on my application. The following code is what i have written but it dosent seem to matter what i do, i cannot get any display in the datagridview on my form. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

code:

```
    Sql = "SELECT * FROM jobList WHERE techID = " & TechScreenID & ""

    connection = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =   C:\Users\Dave\Documents\joblist.mdb;"
    con.ConnectionString = connection
    con.Open()
    Dim adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(Sql, connection)
    Dim results As New DataTable("result")
    adapter.Fill(results)
    con.Close()
    dgwTechStatus.DataSource = results
```

Comment: Have you checked that there is actually data in the table? Also, here is a MSDN tutorial on what you are trying to do http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the datagridview's "autogeneratecolumns" property to true, or add specific bound columns to your datagridview.

Comment: Hi stuart. Do i need to code that? As i cant see that option on my datagridviews property? Thanks for the help!

Comment: `dgwTechStatus.AutoGenerateColumns = true`

Comment: Tried that codingbiz but it still wont display :(

Comment: Yes, just as @codingbiz says. I'll try to add an example one I'm at my pc. (Too hard from tablet :-( )

Comment: Be sure to add autogeneratecolumns = true before setting datasource

Comment: Probably go to the designer and add the columns. Are the column headers showing? and data rows are not?

Comment: Tried that aswell stuart and it still dosent want to give me an output.many thanks for all the help your giving me guys much appreciated.

Comment: codingbiz, im getting nothing, no column headings or rows.

Comment: Did you try and run that query in the Db and it works? Maybe try adding single quote before and after TechScreenID..?

Comment: Tried all of the above guys and still cant get anything but a blank datagridview. Ive got no errorsw...just no output.

Comment: Ty for all responses. Finally sorted it today was an error in my SQL statement.